# Checkout REST API Card Payment Landingpage

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My goal is to redirect the customer directly to the credit card payment page.
[landingpage goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFk8p.png)

Actually, there is a parameter landing_page in the order interface, which sounds to me as if it should do exactly this.
However, no matter which value I use there, the customer is always directed to this page:
[wrong landingpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb8Ke.png)
Do any of you have any idea what I am doing wrong or have already had to deal with this problem? In the old interfaces (Express and Adaptive) it was enough to add a GET parameter to the Paypal link. However, this was not mentioned anywhere in the documentation at the time, but I was only informed of this by Paypal support. I hope for a similar solution with the new interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Add "&fundingSource=card" to the payer-action link to redirect the customer directly to the card payment

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that legacy API parameter. Use a [standard checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for payer approval.

The black "Debit or Credit Card" button, or SEPA button for DE payers, will expand a form or open the relevant landing page. See a demo here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server